# graphs and euclidean space

Tags: graph-theory, euclidean-domain

So, was reading an online blog and it said most real world data comes in the form of graphs and do not lie in a Euclidean space.

I am not able to fully appreciate this comment. What are the properties of the Euclidean space which cannot be present in a graph representation?

Comment: I think this is a situation where you definitely want to link to the original blog post. That statement out of context is too vague to be interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

Distances are not preserved. The distance between two vertices in a graph is defined by the length of a shortest path connected them. But if you try to embed a graph $G$ into a Euclidean metric space, which is equipped with the Euclidean distance metric, it can shorten the distance between those points. The difference between distances in $G$ and in the metric space it embeds into is called the *distortion*. There are more details in these lecture notes: http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs369m/cs369mlecture1.pdf